# Accessing class by other ones in separate files

Tags: c#, class

I don't know if I described my problem correctly - I'm new in Visual Studio, sorry.
I'm writing a program for comunicating via serial port. I wanted to put all the serial port functions (connecting, sending test messages and commands, etc.) in separate file and accessing them by other classes in separate files (e.g. two forms). 
I tried something like this:

```
//serial.cs
namespace test
{
    public class serial
    {
        public byte value;
        public void func()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
        }
    }
}

//main.cs
namespace test
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public static serial s = new serial(); //new object

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            s.value = 10; //set something
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            s.func(); //and display it
        }


    }
}
```

It works, but when I'm inside other file, I need to access my serial object by MainForm.s and it's quite annoying.
I'm looking for some better solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your design, I would suggest to swap the static so that the serial class is static

```
public static class serial
{
    public static byte value;
    public static void func()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then, you only need to do

```
serial.value = 10;
serial.func();
```

Comment: `static` is rarely the answer. What is the benefit of `static` over composition?

Comment: Again, it totally depends on the design here. Since this has mutable state, then I would agree that static would not be a way to go, but maybe it fits the design here. Without more details this solves the problem.

Comment: Justin Pihony, it's awesome... thanks a lot! I don't really know if this solution will be okay for my design (still learning), but for now it's perfect.